# How to get Regular expression for table formated invoice values?

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I want to split the values from Invoice sheets.User will scan the image and I will convert image to text using OCR. I will get the values as string. Now I want to split that invoice values item no, item name , item description, item quantity and price. The table value may contain n number of rows.What regular expression can be used to split those table formatted string values. Any idea would be greatly helpful?

Other than regular expression , please advice me on somethere idea also.

For your reference I have attached sample image of Invoice process:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is item no, item name , item description, item quantity and price in the above image ? put some text example along with the expected outcome....

Comment: Table format won't be helpful, you can get the word before line break and after space

Comment: Item number is 1,2,3.. item name and item descriptions are same, In image one it is Provide labour..... In Image two 1,2,3 are the item numbers followed by item name such as Interior design and spacing planning layout ,...

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman , I want to split those values and show as editable for end users.

Comment: quantity and value are not found in each row... so what is the logic behind merging number, name and quantity and price from different rows ?

Comment: and quantity doesn't even have any shape either, so  what marks a value as a quantity ?

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman : This is sample invoice.. Some invoice might have quantity and price and some might wont have .. My requirement is to split the values from each row..

Comment: So, in the above sample , any quantity value exists ? without knowing that how come you expect an accurate answer ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155875/discussion-between-priya-and-rizwan-m-tuman).